# Receiving error when trying to create list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below is the assignment

> Design a Python script that starts with a list of your own, containing a mix of integers, floating point decimals, and strings. Include this starting list near the beginning of your script. The output of your script should be another list containing only non-string elements in the original list, as follows.

[image]

I'm struggling with how to remove the string elements from the list.  Below is what I have tried, any suggestions?

```
    print("This script starts with a given list and outputs another list containing only non-string elements in the original list.")
    print()
    list1 = [21,99,-99,"cool","school","pool",41.34,-9.034]
    print("The inputted list was:",list1)
    for k in list1:
        if type(k) == str:
            list2 = list1 - k
    print("The output list is:", list2)
```

```
This script starts with a given list and outputs another list containing only non-string elements in the original list.
The inputted list was: [21, 99, -99, 'cool', 'school', 'pool', 41.34, -9.034]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-4e9226325877> in <module>
      5 for k in list1:
      6     if type(k) == str:
----> 7         list2 = list1 - k
      8 print("The output list is:", list2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please don't use images: they are not searchable nor copy-pastable (and this one is unreadable). Please just copy-paste the text, insert it into your question and format it as code.

Comment: You can't subtract from `list`s, only `set`s.

Comment: There is, however, the `.remove()` method.

Comment: Don't mind the downvotes, I think this is a good question. It's clear, it has an example, not too much fluff, everything good to make this answerable. However, have you tried googling what that error means? Usually, the error messages themselves are very useful. Like here: You can not use the operator `-` with a list (`list1`) and a str (`k`). So the best course of action is to figure out how you can actually remove an element from a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `-` to remove an item from list. and remove items from a list you are iterating over

```
print("This script starts with a given list and outputs another list containing only non-string elements in the original list.")
print()
list1 = [21,99,-99,"cool","school","pool",41.34,-9.034]
list2 = []

print("The inputted list was:",list1)

for k in list1:
    if not isinstance(k, str):
        list2.append(k)
print("The output list is:", list2)
```

Comment: You might want to give some explanation. Just dumping code seldom helps.

Comment: you're right, but in this case it's clear. you can't use `-` to remove an element from list. and remove items  from a list you are iterating over. @Matthias